# SQLite Operation Result type

Tags: sqlite, types

I understand the concept of type affinity and have read the "Datatypes In SQLite Version 3". What I don't understand is how two fields, declared as NUM (tried float, double etc) in a CREATE statement and multiplied with each other will generate a result that is type NULL. Is there a way to CAST or coerce or bribe the SQLite to produce a NUM when multyplying two declared NUMs, i.e: NUM * NUM = NUM ?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id varchar(3) primary key not null, x real not null, y real not null)
CREATE TABLE B AS SELECT x * y as z from A.
```

The corresponding statement is

```
CREATE TABLE B(
  id TEXT,
  x REAL,
  y REAL,
  z,
```

Any way I can get a REAL next to the z above?

Comment: Well, the product of a number an a `null` is null...

Comment: To be clear, there is data in A for both x and y, non-null numeric values for both fields. And there are values in B for x,y and z: both x and y are REAL, but z has type NULL. z does contain numeric values however.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the result:

```
CREATE TABLE B AS SELECT CAST(x * y AS REAL) as z from A.
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. The use of cast above does appear in 3.2 "Affinity Of Comparison Operands". Now I've got the context. Thanks ldan.